# Open brace in BibTeX fields

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

How can I enter the following title (of an imaginary book) in a Bib(La)TeX entry: "How to use { in Bib(La)TeX?"

BibTeX suggests that [braces can be backslash-escaped](http://www.bibtex.org/SpecialSymbols/), but both BibTeX processor and Biber fail to process the title if entered this way.

```
@book{test_123,
        title = {How to use \{ in Bib(La)TeX?}
}
```

Biber produces

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.9 running in TOOL mode
INFO - Logfile is 'test.bib.blg'
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'test.bib'
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'test.bib'
WARN - Entry test_123 does not parse correctly
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: C:\*********\test.bib_5644.utf8, line 3, warning: possible runaway string started at line 2
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\********\test.bib_5644.utf8, line 4, syntax error: at end of input, expected one of: number, name (entry type, key, field, or macro name) or quoted string ({...} or "...")
INFO - WARNINGS: 2
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

This also fails in the "abstract" and "file" fields.

I [reported this to the Biber developers](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/61) and was told that someone here might know a trick. Also, this was previously asked (in a roundabout way I guess) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177201/bibtex-biblatex-verbatim-fields-and-special-characters)

Comment: That's invalid input for 'classical' BibTeX too so the failure of Biber to parse this is not really a surprise!

Comment: Right, so how would this be entered in a valid way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [\vphantom command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4519/how-do-i-create-an-invisible-character) to include the closing bracket but not showing it, i.e.

```
@book{test_123,
    title = {How to use \{\vphantom{\}} in Bib(La)TeX?},
    author = {Vinckevicius, Aurimas}
}
```

works for me with normal BibTeX and the following tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{test_123}
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\end{document}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: output pdf]

It might be that (vertical) spacing is slightly influenced.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you elaborate a little bit on your solution, showing an full example and a screen shot of the output?

Comment: Okay, I added a minimal LaTeX example, link to some documentation and a picture of the output.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Biber knows about `\textbraceleft` and tries to translate it into a brace, which kills it. `:(`

Here's a workaround:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testbrace,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={How to use {\biberbraceleft} with Bib(La)\TeX?},
  journal={Trans. \TeX.SX},
  year={2015},
  pages={1-10},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\biberbraceleft}{\textbraceleft}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{testbrace}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I made some experiments: with

```
  title={How to use
    \iftrue\textbraceleft\else\textbraceright\fi
    or
    \iftrue\{\else\}\fi\space with Bib(La)\TeX?},
```

Biber doesn't complain and writes

```
  \field{labeltitle}{How to use \iftrue{\else}\fi or \iftrue\{\else\}\fi\space with Bib(La)\TeX?}
```

so it's evident that there are two problems:

1. `\textbraceleft`, which ought to work, writes instead an unescaped `{`
2. `\{` breaks at Biber processing time, because it's considered as a brace and it's not matched.

A field such as

```
title={\{Braced\}},
```

will work, while

```
title={\textbraceleft Braced\textbraceright},
```

outputs

```
\field{title}{{Braced}}
```

which is clearly a bad bug in Biber.

Comment: Ugh. That's unfortunate. Should Biber really be expanding that macro though? I can take this upstream to Biber if that's actually an issue. I'm working on a BibTeX export filter for Zotero, so the above solution, while great, is not really something I can apply.

Comment: @Aurimas Working on it. But using `\{` seems out of question.

Comment: This was a bug in biber and is fixed in the current DEV branch. `\textbraceleft` and `\textbractright` are now excluded from UTF8 decoding (they were already excluded from encoding). `\{` is out of the question as it would require changes in the underlying parser.

Comment: @PLK Thanks for confirming my suspect. I can understand that working on unbalanced `\{` might not be worthy the effort. Maybe a note in the manuals could be added. You could consider about adding something like `\providecommand\gobble[1]{}` in the LaTeX code, so that an unbalanced braces can be input as `\{\gobble\}` or `\gobble\{\}` to keep the parser happy.